# What is the difference between caloric and heat? Is there any?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the difference between heat and caloric? Is there a difference?

Comment: Isn't [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) a better site for this question?

Comment: Useful to review ["Teaching Heat: the Rise and Fall of the Caloric Theory"](http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/more_stuff/TeachingHeat.htm) and the references within.

Answer (score 2):

The caloric theory was the theory that considered heat as a self-repellent fluid called caloric that flows from hotter to colder bodies.

Now we define heat as the mode of energy transfer between bodies at different temperatures. The transfer can be conductive, convective or radiative.

Comment: Also see ["Heat is not a noun"](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1341254), which aims to clarify how thinking of heat as a substance (as caloric was theorized to be) rather than a mode can lead to confusion.